# removing forward slash in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am using Jobbersbase for my online job portal. In which i have given link to my main webpage page like this `http://www.mydomain.com/aboutus.html,` but its not working because the link is taking '`/`' at the end `http://www.mydomain.com/aboutus.html/`

I tried adding `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f` in .htaccess , if i add that other links doesnt work which has `/` for example `http://www.mydomain.com/jobs/`

Now my .htaccess looks like this

```
# AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
# AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php

    RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*/$
RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1



ErrorDocument 404 /page-unavailable/

<files ~ "\.tpl$">
order deny,allow
allow from none
deny from all
</files>
```

Someone please suggest me how to do it
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it isn't as easy as I imagine, but:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*/$
RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1
```

With modifications for the specific files/directories you care about, if necessary. See below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*aboutus\.html/$ [or]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*contact\.html/$
RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1
```

This should strip trailing slashes from those specific pages only. Unfortunately I can't verify this because I'm having trouble getting my `.htaccess` working with my virtual host configuration.

Comment: if i add these two lines all my site goes off :(. only text displays.

Comment: i am not getting how to add specific files . please help me in this

Comment: @user1083644 I've updated my response with the proper syntax, sorry. Last night I wasn't thinking clearly and had the wrong answer. Just tested now and this version works - the trailing slash is removed.

Comment: Thanks a ton Chris, But still its not working. The other links which have / are also doesn't work. I have edited my code above. Like that i have put. Please have a look and suggest

Comment: Could you give an example of URLs that are not working, with a link to the actual pages if at all possible?

Comment: Please check with this link
`www.lisaprofessionals.com/jobs/` - here in footer about us and contact us are taking `http://lisaprofessionals.com/aboutus.html/` it should be `http://lisaprofessionals.com/aboutus.html/`. like this. But if i put the code as you directed, other links ie, `http://www.lisaprofessionals.com/jobs/job/26/lisa-tester-at-sample-ads-ltd/` and `http://www.lisaprofessionals.com/jobs/job/27/wdwdewd-at-name123/` ... will not work

Comment: @user1083644 I think my last edit may work now. Unfortunately I can't test it but I am hopeful.